# setup WiFi with no password to connect but Password to Surf Internet

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

How to set up wifi that requires no password to connect but ask password to browse the internet?
Does it require different kind of router, can it be done in a Microtech router or we need servers for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is commonly referred to as a *[captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)*, similar to the ones you may have seen at hotels or restaurants where they require you to enter a room number or click through a usage agreement page.  There are many products which offer this capability, commercial and open source.  I can't find any information on Microtech routers.  There may be options depending on the model number and underlying chipset, especially if it is a rebranding of a more common brand.    If you meant MikroTik, then there are definitely options that will work with those.

Some routers can completely run a simple captive portal on board the router.  DD-WRT is a firmware that works on many routers and includes ChilliSpot, a captive portal.  Other solutions require you to set up a separate server to authenticate users.  Another common method is to have your router authenticate users via a hotspot subscription service like Sputnik or WiFiDog where the user and password management is outsourced, and all you have to do is tell the router to use that service.

It may be worth looking at projects like [PacketFence](http://www.packetfence.org/) and [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) to get an idea of what can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

You could use capture software. This would involve setting up your DHCP to use your router as server A and then install capture software on server A so only computers who are authenticated are allowed through. This allows for the classic coffee shop-style flow.

Answer (score 0):

You need captive portal to be configured on your router. For your setup you will have your ESSID configured without any authentication (Open access) and Captive portal configured for that ESSID. Now when a user tries to access internet then user will be redirected to a landing page instead where he/she will be asked to authenticate themselves using username and password.

You should be able to do this with Mikrotik routers, you will need to configure hotspot on your router using WinBox application which Mikrotik provides.

You will find more details about configuring it from here http://www.mikrotik.com.my/hotspot-server-with-captive-portal-and-walled-garden/